# How to read a csv file in C?

Tags: c, csv, import

I am trying to read a CSV file in C. The CSV file contains one column and 1024 rows. The CSV file contains only decimal numbers. So far I have this code, but the numbers from the output and the CSV file do not match. The CSV file is called file.csv

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IL2mB.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xRjfY.png)

```
int main(void)
{
    FILE *stream;
    errno_t err;

    err = fopen_s(&stream, "file.csv", "r");
    if (stream == NULL) {
        printf("\n file opening failed ");
        return -1;
    }

    double values[1024];
    int count;
    for (count = 0; count < 1024; count++) {

        double u = fscanf_s(stream, "%d", &values[count]);
        printf("%d\n", u);
    }

return(0);

}
```

Comment: Paste the actual contents of the first few lines of the file into the question as text, not as an image.

Answer (score 1):

Scan into and print `double` objects using `%lg`, not `%d`.

The return type of `fscanf_s` is an `int`, not a `double`. Test it to see if the desired number of items were assigned (one, in your case), and, if not, print an error message and exit the program.

Comment: I changed %d to %lg. However, I still get as output integer values. Is there a similar function of fscanf_s with return type as a double? Do you know what "errno_t err;" is doing?

Comment: There is no variant of `fscanf_s` that returns a `double`, and there should not be, as the information returned is inherently an integer: The number of items assigned or `EOF` if end-of-file or an I/O error occurs before the first match. Use the return value of `fscanf_s` to test for errors, not to receive scanned values. Scanned values are communicated via the pointer passed to `fscanf_s` by `&values[count]`.

Comment: `errno_t err;` defines `err` as a variable of type `errno_t`, which is the type returned by `fopen_s`. As with the return value of `fscanf_s`, you should test the return value to see whether an error occurred. If it is not zero, an error occurred.

Comment: I did test it and no error occurred in the command window. However, I did not get as aspected 1024 values printed out as an output.